# Equivalent of a sequence in regard to a certain length of a cycle for $\mathfrak{S}_{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, permutations, asymptotics, symmetric-groups

Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ ( for me $0\notin \Bbb{N})$.

> Find the limit as $n$ tends to $+ \infty$ of the following sequence $$\frac{\alpha_{n}}{n}$$ where $\alpha_{n}$ is the number of permutations of $\mathfrak{S}_{n}$ which all length cycles are less  than  $\frac{n}{2}$.

My try,

If $n$ is even we just need to break the set into two parts and notice that all hyperbolic subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_{n}$ stabilizing both parts works, so we have $\alpha_n\ge (\frac{n}{2}!)^2$. Then the limit is $+ \infty$. How can I do for $n$ odd ?

**An additional question**

Can we find a 'simple' equivalent of $\alpha_{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count the number of permutations with a cycle of length $\ge n/2$. It can only have one such cycle, for obvious reasons. First, pick a natural $n/2\le k\le n$. Next, pick a $k$-cycle from $S_n$, and finally the rest of the cycle decomposition can be determined by choosing any permutation on the set of elements in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ not already present in our first chosen cycle.

Therefore,

$$\alpha_n=n!-\sum_{n/2\le k\le n} \frac{(n)_k}{k}(n-k)!=n!\left(1-\sum_{n/2\le k\le n}\frac{1}{k}\right).$$

Above, $(q)_k:=\overbrace{q(q-1)(q-2)\cdots}^k$ is the falling factorial. The number of sequences of length $k$ of elements of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ with no repetitions is $(n)_k$, so we divide this by $k$ to get the total number of cycles in $S_n$ of length $k$. There are $n-k$ elements in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ not present in a given $k$-cycle, which means our final choice is from $(n-k)!$ possible permutations. Clearly $(n)_k(n-k)!=n!$ so we used that to simplify.

Assuming the question was for $\alpha_n/n!$, we can use the estimate $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log n+\gamma+o(1)$ for the harmonic numbers to conclude that $\alpha_n/n!$ converges to $\color{Red}{1-\log 2}$.

Comment: Here we are looking for cycle of length $\le n/2$..

Comment: @MarcGato There are two types of permutations: those that have a cycle of length $\ge n/2$, and those that have all cycles with size $<n/2$. Since you know the total number of permutations, counting one is equivalent to counting the other. (You did read the "$n!-\rm blah$" in my answer, no?) Also, small technical point, your problem statement seems to indicate $<n/2$ strictly, not $\le n/2$.

Comment: You are right, silly comment. Thanks a lot for this answer. (+1)

Comment: It was a fun question.